# How can I remove a duplicate variable definition, without hindering my game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make a game, but flash is giving me this warning code:

Scene 1, Layer 'roachLevel', Frame 1, Line 98   Warning: 3596: Duplicate variable definition.

Everytime I remove the "duplicate variable" it hinders my game, and the game won't work correctly anymore.
This is the code where the warning is occurring:

```
function moveEnemies():void
{
var tempEnemy:MovieClip;


for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
     var tempEnemy=enemies[i];
if (tempEnemy.dead) 
{
    score++;
    score++;
    roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
    enemies.splice(i,1);
} 



     else // Enemy is still alive and moving across the screen
    {
        //rotate the enemy between 10-5 degrees
        tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
        //Find the rotation and move the x position that direction
        tempEnemy.x -=  (Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
        tempEnemy.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
        if (tempEnemy.x < 10)
        {
            tempEnemy.x = 11;
        }
        if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
        {
             tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
        }
        if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
        {
            removeEnemy(i);

            lives--;
            roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think simply replacing `var tempEnemy=enemies[i];` with `tempEnemy=enemies[i];` will solve your issue

Comment: Did you already resolve your issue?